# conditional formatting - if and statement

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I am working on an if/and statement in conditional formatting.

I have 2 sheets. --- YTD Summary and Parameters

I want to conditional format the following 'YTD Summary'! I11:I31
      These are set up as Percentages. The Parameters page has cell B2 with one of the following variables depending on what month it is (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc.)

the formulas I have tried are as follows

AND(Parameters!$B$2="Oct,'YTD Summary'!$I$11<(3/12-.05))

and(Parameters!B2="Oct",'YTD Summary'!I11<3/12-.05)

Conditional formatting takes the formula, but doesn't turn any of the percentages red within the specified range (I11:I31). Yes, I have formatted it for red text. Any help would be much appreciated. I have spent way to much time on this. thank you, Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AND(Parameters!B$2="Oct",I11<0.2)
```

[image]

This worked for me. If the B$2 reference needs to move downward with the values in I, then remove the $ before 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was hoping my co-workers could look at the formula and see how I came up with the answer, but I will reference it somewhere else. Thank you for your quick reply. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MattLane If you mean that you want to include the (3/12 - .05) in the formula, you still can. I removed it because I thought that might be causing a problem. But the issue was actually with the absolute references. Column I should move (no $s), column B shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry, How did you get it to travel down for I11:I31? I cant get it to go down. Thanks, Matt        =AND(Parameters!B$2="Oct",I11<3/12-0.05)

Comment: Did you select that entire range when you applied the conditional format?

Comment: I thought it was. I just deleted the rule and started over. it works great. Thank you for your follow ups in helping me! have a great week.